# A responsive Cover Image Menu thing

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I can make it work but as soon as I try resizing it to make sure it's responsive, it scales very weird. Basically, I need the pictures to be their natural size and be lined up next to each other without any white space. Also, the text needs to in the middle.

I put it all in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rgk6nuo/) and here's a [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmeCJ.jpg). The gif is more important so you can see my problem.

Thanks for your help, I just can't figure this out.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<div class="aktivnostiList">

<div class="spacer">
</div>

    <div class="coverRevija">
        <img class="covers" src="file:\\C:\Users\andre\Desktop\karolin\web\hr\projekti\revija\revijacover.jpg">
        <div id="linkRevija"><h3 id="emphasis"><a href="#">Modna revija</a></h3></div>
    </div>

    <div class="spacerSmall"></div>

    <div class="coverCajanka">
        <img class="covers" src="file:\\C:\Users\andre\Desktop\karolin\web\hr\projekti\cajanka\cajankacover.jpg">
        <div id="linkCajanka"><h3 id="emphasis"><a href="#">Čajanka</a></h3></div>
    </div>

    <div class="spacerSmall"></div>

    <div class="coverIzlozba">
        <img class="covers" src="file:\\C:\Users\andre\Desktop\karolin\web\hr\projekti\izlozba\izlozbacover.jpg">
        <div id="linkIzlozba"><h3 id="emphasis"><a href="#">Izložba</a></h3></div>
    </div>
```

```
.aktivnostiIntro{
width: 75%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 100px;
text-align: center;
}

.covers{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
left: 0;
}

.aktivnostiList{
text-align: center;
}

.coverRevija{
line-height: 227px;
}

.coverCajanka{
line-height: 227px;
}

.coverIzlozba{
line-height: 227px;
}
```

Comment: you need to upload your images to somewhere we can see them, currently they are sourcing from your local machine - no one can see them except you!

Comment: Or use image placeholders.

Comment: I know I know, I just didn't consider it important since I provided a gif. What do you mean by image placeholders though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are scaling proportionately - as you reduce the width, the height is reducing too (to maintain the image's aspect ratio). If you want the images to keep their height, you could change them from `<img>` tags in the html to `background-images` in the css. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/9rgk6nuo/7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="aktivnostiList">

    <div class="spacer">
    </div>

        <div class="covers-wrapper coverRevija">
            <div id="linkRevija"><h3 id="emphasis"><a href="#">Modna revija</a></h3></div>
        </div>

        <div class="spacerSmall"></div>

        <div class="covers-wrapper coverCajanka">
            <div id="linkCajanka"><h3 id="emphasis"><a href="#">Čajanka</a></h3></div>
        </div>

        <div class="spacerSmall"></div>

        <div class="covers-wrapper coverIzlozba">
            <div id="linkIzlozba"><h3 id="emphasis"><a href="#">Izložba</a></h3></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.aktivnostiIntro{
    width: 75%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.covers-wrapper {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.aktivnostiList{
    text-align: center;
    }

.coverRevija{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1200x300'); //change this to your image source
    line-height: 227px;
}

.coverCajanka{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1200x300'); //change this to your image source
    line-height: 227px;
}

.coverIzlozba{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1200x300'); //change this to your image source
    line-height: 227px;
}
```

Comment: I am forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this update your css .covers class

```
`  .covers{
         min-width: 100%;
         height:100%;
         position: absolute;
         z-index: -1;
         left: 0;
     }`
```